# Spotfire - How to group multiple columns under a single column in data table visualization

Tags: header, multiple-columns, spotfire, tibco, calculation

How to group multiple columns under a single column in data table visualization

Please see attached image[image]

Answer (score 2):

@BULB - You can transform your table by unpivoting and pivoting data to get the desired result.

I first un-pivoted the original data table by applying transformation.

```
INSERT > Transformations
```

[image]

Then pivoted the unpivot output by applying another transformation.

*Note: You can apply both the transformations simultaneously.*

[image]

***Final Output:***

[image]