# Spotfire Average over a column

Tags: average, spotfire

I have a question related to Spotfire. I have a table

[image]

And what I need to get is an Average of the rate (Operational Costs/Production) grouped by Region. Mathematically it looks like this for Europe: ((Costs A 2017 + Costs B 2017)/(Production A 2017 + Production B 2017) + (Costs A 2018 + Costs B 2018)/(Production A 2018 + Production B 2018) + (Costs A 2019 + Costs B 2019)/(Production A 2019 + Production B 2019)) / 3

and do the same for Asia. So basically, I need to calculate the rate for the Region and find an average over the years. can't figure out, how to do this.

Comment: can you please provide sample expected results?

Answer (score 0):

@user2538414- I would suggest you to add a pivot transformation to your original table to make it more readable and easy to work with.

Please check the below post which explains how to pivot and unpivot data tables.
[Spotfire - How to group multiple columns under a single column in data table visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46766637/spotfire-how-to-group-multiple-columns-under-a-single-column-in-data-table-vis/46789120#46789120)

**Transformed Table:**

[image]

To this transformed table you can add a calculated column with the custom expression below to compute Rate (Costs/Production) by Region and year.

```
Sum([Costs]) over (intersect([Region],[Year])) / Sum([Production]) over (intersect([Region],[Year]))
```

You can further refine this custom expression to suit your requirement.

**Final output table:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks! And how can I get then average of rate for certain years? I need now average of "rate by Region&Year" for 2017-2018 vs 2018-2019 on a Bar chart